# How to remove &#133; from URL using htaccess or other method

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have an issue where people are getting to my site with invalid characters in the URL. I am able to resolve most of them except for this.

> `/random-text/Page+Title&#133;/?other-cool-stuff`

I need to rewrite the URL so it does not include `&#133;` which is sending those visitors to a 404 page.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.
Doesn't change in .htaccess though.

Comment: Someone hit a link on Google and ended up there, a little too late for urlencode. Which is why I'm looking for a .htaccess solution.

Comment: What is generating your URLs then? Can you change it before this point?

Comment: Yes, I found where the URL was being generated and fixed it. But there are still some indexed links out there people are clicking on.

Comment: Maybe you can customize your 404 page to deal with it? Just a thought.